# OpenCV - ArUco: Pose estimation for rectangle-shaped markers

Tags: opencv, aruco

Does the `cv2.aruco` library support pose estimation of rectangle-shaped ArUco marker?

I've found that `cv2.aruco.detectMarkers` detects the rectangle-shaped ArUco marker but `cv2.aruco.estimatePoseSingleMarkers` supports only square-shaped marker

Comment: you could try defining a "board". IIRC the definition takes the four individual corners of each marker.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Can u point to some links?